# Unable to export IES lights in glb/gltf formats

Tags: lighting, gltf

We are trying to use IES lights and export in glb format so that we can get same effect from Babylonjs.

While exporting in gltf format, we selected below options.

Still we are unable to export IES lights, pls suggest

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think IES lights can be exported to any standard model formats today, unfortunately. You'd need to either bake the lighting, or create the lighting in babylon.js directly.

There have been some efforts to add IES to glTF. Not officially by Khronos Group, and not widely supported, but:

- https://forum.babylonjs.com/t/ies-light-profile-support/36088
- https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/pull/2200
- https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/main/extensions/2.0/Vendor/EXT_lights_ies/README.md

I might recommend asking Babylon.js if they support this `EXT_lights_ies` extension. If so, then you could file an issue at https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues and see if the Blender addon developers are open to supporting it as well.